# Javascript messing up POST-request for PHP-file?

Tags: php, javascript, httprequest

I got following scenario:

A site is sending a request to a php-file to hand me some data. For this request I am selecting an item - here is the code for that part:

```
<form action="?modul=transaktionen&subModul=monitor" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="suchVal" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="1">
<!-- A LOT OF STUFF INBETWEEN ... -->
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input  type="radio" 
                name="hostsARR[host][idGcomp]" 
                id="nod_331" 
                value="331">
    </td>
    <td>Some text which is really not important</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input  type="radio" 
                name="hostsARR[host][idGcomp]" 
                id="nod_332" 
                value="332">
    </td>
    <td>more text that is not important</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<input type="submit" class="sendButton" name="edit" value="Show details">
</form>
```

And when I select one of these item and hit the button it should send me the request with these attributes:

```
action                    1
edit                      Show details
hostsARR[host][idGcomp]   332
```

It does that normally, but when I add javascript to it it gets totally messed up! It does not send the right request. What happens is that I do not get the `hostsARR`. Everything else gets through. I added a script by frequency-decoder.com for pagination and for sorting. You can find the script here if you need a look at it: http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2007/10/19/client-side-table-pagination-script.
Basically my question is whether there are known Javascripts or bugs or whatever I don't know or am not capable of giving a name for that mess up POST (or other) requests?

Seriously this is driving me crazy as I really do not see a reason why sorting a table or rather adding javascript should alter a form element to that extent.

Thnx in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** The request doesn't work anywhere BUT IE ... dunno where IE is maybe more tolerant?

Comment: Can you post the code for getting the values in JavaScript?

Comment: It is not an javascript-based request ... as you can see it is a normal html form element for sending the request. the javascript was just added for some client-side sorting and pagination ... that is where I start wondering, but I guess it is just b/c I am not seeing something!

Comment: Sure there are JavaScript/DOM bugs. Yep, a bug could be hitting you. Can we answer what bug in this situation? Nope, because you've not shown enough context - it's not clear how the DOM and JavaScript are interacting in your case. Perhaps provide a link to you're problem page?

Comment: So the way the javascript alters the DOM could change the way the request is built up? I think I hate the idea! :( I will try to hit together a working example to show what happens.

Comment: working as in "not working" ... I mean, displaying what goes wrong!

Comment: This is something to take up with that script's author; JavaScript itself doesn't mess with your input fields, but apparently the script does (to do its pagination and sorting, presumably).

Comment: So it is in the script somewhere? Do you have idea (not from the script itself, more generally as an example) what could alter the input-fields? I forgot to mention that it WORKS in IE, but not in FF or Opera ...

Comment: sorry, but I can't upload anything right now (@ work) so does anybody have a general idea or could give me a hint what could change an input field so badly that it is not seen as part of a request?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the information given, I can conclude that the pagination or sorting script has nothing to do with what causes your error.

My guess is that your manual actions have caused this or some other included script.
But unless you provide us these no-one can tell.

If you could provide the full source to recreate the problem we could all be of more help.